# Embed and display PDF viewer

Tags: 8, files

I'm looking for a solution to display some of my PDF files with a viewer.

I found many solutions for Drupal 7 but not yet for Drupal 8.

Is there any module or open source solution to display PDFs in a Viewer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Embedded Google Docs Viewer](https://www.drupal.org/project/gdoc_field) module for that

> **Drupal 8**
>
> This module provides a formatter for the File field type. This
>   formatter presents the file as a fully rendered object within a web
>   page - i.e. it displays the contents of the file as appropriate to its
>   filetype (Adobe Acrobat **.pdf**, Microsoft Word .doc/.docx, Microsoft
>   Excel .xls/.xlsx, Microsoft Powerpoint .ppt/.pptx), using the Google
>   Docs embedded rendering engine.

There are some other modules but those are in Dev version. Have a look at the [Comparison of PDF viewer modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1781960)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will not use any viewer after all <embed src="http://example.com/the.pdf" width="500" height="375" type='application/pdf'>